# Trying to edit ArrayLists passed by WIldcard

Tags: java, wildcard, extends

I'm trying to make a maintenance method for a game my friend and I are working on, which basically checks of the bullet is outside of set boundaries and then moves it from the one ArrayList (alive) to another (dead).

We have a number of ArrayLists, containing different types of bullets which extend from the class Bullet_Enemy.

the maintenance class is as follows (Using Java):

```
public void maintenance(ArrayList<? extends Bullet_Enemy> aliveList, ArrayList<? extends Bullet_Enemy> deadList)
{    for(i = 0; i < aliveList.size(); i++)
     {    if(aliveList.get(i).[Position] [is] [outside Boundary])
          {     deadList.add(aliveList.get(i));
                aliveList.get(i).reset();
                aliveList.remove(i);
           }
      }
 }
```

The problem I'm having is that at the line "deadList.add(aliveList.get(i));" is telling me that there's an error:

```
"The method add(capture#33-of ? extends Bullet_Enemy) in the type ArrayList<capture#33-of ? extends Bullet_Enemy> is not applicable for the arguments (capture#34-of ? extends Bullet_Enemy)"
```

I'm not really sure where to even start on this problem - Even what terms to search around on google would be helpful, as would someone explaining why this problem is happening.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the two `?`'s are not guaranteed to be of the same type.

So you can have `ArrayList<Bullet_Enemy_SubClass1>` and `ArrayList<Bullet_Enemy_SubClass2>` as your parameters, but obviously `Bullet_Enemy_SubClass1` and `Bullet_Enemy_SubClass2` are not compatible.

Assuming you're happy that they must be the same type, you can fix this by making the method signature:

```
public <T extends Bullet_Enemy> void maintenance(ArrayList<T> aliveList,
                                                 ArrayList<T> deadList)
```

But it seems that you really want to allow any `Bullet_Enemy` types in the `ArrayList`s (not limit each of these to a single type), in which case you should use `ArrayList<Bullet_Enemy>`:

```
public void maintenance(ArrayList<Bullet_Enemy> aliveList,
                        ArrayList<Bullet_Enemy> deadList)
```

This will still allow adding `Bullet_Enemy_SubClass1` and `Bullet_Enemy_SubClass2` to the `ArrayList`s, you'll just have to cast them if you want to use a method of `Bullet_Enemy_SubClass1` or `Bullet_Enemy_SubClass2`, i.e.:

```
((Bullet_Enemy_SubClass1)aliveList.get(0)).subClass1Method();

// cast not required if we want to use a method of Bullet_Enemy
aliveList.get(0).bulletEnemyMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked flawlessly!
I ended up using the first method, as the second was basically what I had just switched away from (basically I couldn't pass an ArrayList<Bullet_Enemy_Subclass1> because although Bullet_Enemy_Subclass1 extended Bullet_Enemy, the ArrayList of Bullet_Enemy_Subclass1 didn't extend the ArrayList of Bullet_Enemy or some such. All is well now though, thanks!